# I want to Empty the Value of 2 Input-Type-Text, On Checked (Box)

Tags: javascript, html

Guys I Need Help I have the Code what can Empty the Value of Single Input by ID i have 2 Input lets say Start time and End time When i Click on All Day it should be Empty Start Time and End Time When i Check this Button... 
Here is my Code....

```
<Input type="text" id="startime" />
<input type="text" id="endtime" />  
<input type="check" id="remove" />

<script type="text/javascript">
            var imgInput = document.getElementById('startime'),
                remove = document.getElementById('remove'),
                val = imgInput.value;

            remove.onchange = function() {
                if (this.checked) {
                    imgInput.value = "";
                } else {
                    imgInput.value = val;
                }
            }
</script>
```

Help Appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

For a checkbox, you should not use the onchange event handler, onclick will do what you need:

```
        remove.onclick = function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                imgInput.value = "";
            } else {
                imgInput.value = val;
            }
        }
```

However it looks like you might be trying to save the value if it gets cleared so it can be repopulated, if this is the case then you also need to update val before you clear the text box:

```
        remove.onclick = function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                val = imgInput.value;
                imgInput.value = "";
            } else {
                imgInput.value = val;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Friend Thanks for your answer but it still not working i m not very good in js, it just when i click back on first text field nothing happen on the other, would u please explain a little bit further to make it work???

Comment: I noticed your remove checkbox had a type of check, where it should be checkbox. There was also nothing in the code to handle the end time. I've made a fiddle that does something, not exactly sure if it's what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/cheeseweasel/PJe2w/

Comment: No problem, you're more than welcome to mark this the correct answer then. ;)